# Can my answer be undeleted?

Tags: discussion

Re: [Why is the lowest note on the piano an A?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/29675/why-is-the-lowest-note-on-the-piano-an-a/41237#41237)

It's wrong. But wrong answers are answers, too!

It's also an awesome piece of Classic Neo-Platonic Art.

And it's funny.

Laugh.

You can downvote it, as a "vote against obsolete ideas" if you like.

But it also reinforces an obvious answer to *why begin there?* viz. *because that's where the letters begin*. A B C.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that that answer is more of a comment rather than an answer. It's not that it's wrong per se, but the answers are usually used for answers; wrong and correct ones alike.

You can add that as a comment to the question. We've had  many funny comments that don't really *help* the question, but they are good and are not deleted.

Comment: It would also be deleted as a comment,  though -- it's just noise. Humor is OK as part of something helpful, but pure joke comments will eventually be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to agree with Shevliaskovic - it isn't an answer. It is a comment, and one I found funny, but it doesn't attempt to answer the question, so from a site perspective deleting it is correct.

If you want to add it as a comment, it doesn't add anything (other than a bit of humour) but as Shev says, we do keep a fair few of those around if they get enough up votes.